# Syncfusion ej2 Angular Spreadsheet shows OData metadata columns

Tags: angular, spreadsheet, syncfusion

I'm currently trying to display arbitrary data from a datasource in an Angular spreadsheet component using the syncfusion ej2 spreadsheet for angular. I created an ODataController and get my data via the ODataV4Adaptor. This actually works but I have the problem that the spreadsheet also displays the metadata of my data fields.

Here's an example:

Backend model:

```
public class DataImportRowData
{
    [Key]
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public int Index1 { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Data { get; set; }
    
    public IDictionary<string, object> RowData =>
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(Data);
}
```

As you can see the RowData contains my JSON data from the database as additional dynamic properties, e.g.:

```
"value": [
{
"Id": 128850,
"Index1": 2,
"No@odata.type": "#Int64",
"No": 1,
"Type@odata.type": "#Int64",
"Type": 1,
"Birthday@odata.type": "#DateTimeOffset",
"Birthday": "1965-03-27T00:00:00+01:00"
}
]
```

where No, Type and Birthday are the JSON properties. I then define the data in the frontend via the DataManager class:

```
public data?: DataManager;
this.data = new DataManager({
            url: 'xxxx?$orderby=Index1',
            adaptor: new ODataV4Adaptor(),
            crossDomain: true
          });
```

Here's the HTML template:

```
<ejs-spreadsheet #spreadsheet [height]="1000" (created)="created(dataImport)">
   <e-sheets>
     <e-sheet [name]="dataImport.name">
       <e-ranges>
         <e-range [dataSource]="data"></e-range>
       </e-ranges>
     </e-sheet>
   </e-sheets>
 </ejs-spreadsheet>
```

When I start the application, the data gets displayed in the spreadsheet control, but it also displays the OData metadata attributes:
[image]

Has anyone an idea why this is happening and how I can get rid of these columns?
Another issue I have is the format of the date field in the picture, does anyone know how to format this column suitable for my needs?

Answer (score 0):

Query #1: Showing oData metadata attributes.

We suspect you have mentioned the data source header (Id, Index1, etc.) as metadata attributes on your end. So, we suggest you set the showFieldAsHeader property to false to remove the headers in the spreadsheet, as shown below. If this does not fulfill your requirement, please get back to us with more details, like the term metadata attributes on your end. Based on that, we can validate further.
|<ejs-spreadsheet

```
#remoteDataBinding

[openUrl]="openUrl"

[saveUrl]="saveUrl"

(queryCellInfo)="queryCellInfo($event)"
```

> 

```
<e-sheets>

  <e-sheet name="Shipment Details">

    <e-ranges>

      <e-range

        [showFieldAsHeader]="false"

        startCell="A1"

        [dataSource]="data"

      >

      </e-range>

    </e-ranges>



    

  </e-sheet>

</e-sheets>
```

|

Query #2: To set date format for date formatted value in spreadsheet.

Your requirement can be achieved by assigning the value of the converted date formatted values in the cell using the setCell method in the queryCellInfo event, as shown in the following.

|queryCellInfo(args) {

```
// Apply date format for G column



let sheet = this.spreadsheetObj.getActiveSheet();

if (args.colIndex == 6) {

  let intl: Internationalization = new Internationalization();

  setCell(

    args.rowIndex,

    args.colIndex,

    sheet,

    {

      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',

      value: intl

        .formatDate(new Date(args.cell.value), {

          type: 'date',

          format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',

        })

        .toString(),

    },

    true

  );

}
```

}

|

We have prepared the sample based on our suggestions. In this, we have loaded the data source using oDataV4Adaptor and assigned the date format for dated values in the G column. Please find the sample link below.

Sample Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ryxbee?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank your for your answer and sorry for the late response.
No I did not mean the headers as metadata but the fields `@odata.type`, e.g. Column C (`No@odata.type`) in my screenshot above which shows the data type `#Int64` of the field `No`. The oData endpoint adds that information automatically but I do not want these fields displayed